# Search and Replace Scanner not publishing nodes after search?

Tags: search, nodes

I'm using the handy [Search and Replace Scanner](https://drupal.org/project/scanner) module to do a basic sitewide search. It's working well... except that it's not publishing the nodes after the it does the replace. It's making new unpublished revisions. This is quite annoying because then I have to go to all 50+ nodes that were changed and publish them all.

Is there any way around this? Ideally, I'd like the nodes to just be published after the replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a node setup thing. Adjusted Workflow/Revision settings to auto-publish, and we're all good.